# Claim to get my source code used GPL code

Tags: licensing, open-source, gpl

I'm running public web site based on Drupal. Drupal is GPL 2 or 3 licence. Of course I wrote custom code which interacts with Drupal code (modules). Can anybody write me an e-mail and ask for the source code of that my custom code? In other words, have I to publish that my code somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your code is sitting on a web server and you are only serving web pages (or web services containing application data), then you are not "distributing" under the terms of the GPL 2 or GPL 3.

The Affero GPL is the one that requires you to release your source code if you are distributing web pages using software under that license.

Answer (score 5):

[GPL](https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-general-public-license-v3-%28gpl-3%29) restricts distribution of source code. Your Drupal code is server side, it lives on your server and no client can see it. It's not really been distributed. So, you don't have to release your code if you don't want to.

As stated in the other answer, the [Affero GPL](https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-affero-general-public-license-v3-%28agpl-3.0%29) is the GPL variant that requires you to release (which would be the same as distribute) the code you're using to publish your web pages (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351119/if-i-use-gnu-gpl-code-with-my-own-server-side-code-do-i-need-to-open-my-server)).

Do note, however, that this applies to server side code. You [should be careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239470/restrictions-of-gpl-on-javascript-libraries) with [Javascript](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62869/how-is-client-side-javascript-covered-by-the-gpl), since that code actually makes it to the client's machines.